# How to pass an array object from a component to a page in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, components

Child

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

import "../pages/All.css";

const MovieList = (props) => {
    return(
    <>
        {props.movies.map((movie, index) => (

            <div className="ro">
                <img src={movie.Poster} alt={movie.Title} /> <br /> <br />
                <label>{movie.Title}</label>  <br />
                <p>{movie.Type} {movie.Year}</p> <br /> <br />
                <div className="overlay">
                    <li><Link to = "/play" class="popup-video btn">Watch</Link></li> &nbsp; &nbsp;
                    <li><Link to ="movie-details.html" class="btn">Download</Link></li>
                </div>
            </div>
        ))}
    </>
    );
};

export default MovieList;
```

```
import React from "react";
import ReactPlayer from "react-player";

function Play(movie){
    return(
        <div>
             <ReactPlayer width="100%" height="750px" controls url ={"http://www.youtube.com/"+movie.Title} />
        </div>
    );
}


export default Play;
```

i am trying to pass {movie.Title} to controls url in Parent Component

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what you're trying to do?

Comment: I can't see a parent component in your code example. The parent component must import and implement the child component `MovieList`. Please update your code.

Answer (score 0):

I hope what you want to ask is how to pass params.

```
const MainNavigation = ()=> (
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<VideoList />} />
    <Route path="/play:id" element={<Play />} />
  </Routes>
)

const VideoList = ()=> (
  <Link to={"/play/" + movie.title}>{movie.title}</Link>
)

const Play = ()=> {
  const {id} = useParams();

  return (
    <VideoComponent url={"https://example.com/" + id} />
  )
}
```

For more information, read official documents. https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/hooks/use-params